# What is the use case of eqT rather than cast?

Tags: haskell

In `Data.Typeable` there is a function cast

```
cast :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
```

and a function `eqT`

```
eqT :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Maybe (a :~: b)
```

They seem to be nearly identical in effect and implementation, I was wondering if there is any practical import to the description of eqT: *extract a witness of equality of two types*.

Comment: You can easily implement `cast` from `eqT`. While you can also implement `eqT` from `cast`, it's not as obvious IMO (I thought this was impossible at first! I recommend to try it as an exercise.). This is because `eqT` allows `case eqT @a @b of Just Refl -> ...` which tells the compiler to assume `a~b` in the `...`, and this assumption is automatically handled by the compiler as needed, which is very powerful. By comparison, `cast` only allows to convert `a` into (maybe) `b` and that alone does not instruct the type checker to assume anything.

Answer (score 4):

This is awkward:

```
checkEq :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b, Eq b) => a -> a -> Maybe Bool
checkEq a a' = do
    b  <- cast @_ @b a
    b' <- cast a'
    pure (b == b')
```

Internally, that checks the cast twice, and does two `Maybe` pattern matches. But once we've done one cast, we *know* the other will succeed!

This is better:

```
checkEq a a' = (\Refl -> a == a') <$> eqT @a @b
```

Just one check, just one `Maybe` pattern match.

This kind of thing often comes up when you have existentially-quantified `Typeable` things in data structures, and want to do operations on them that take multiple arguments. Bringing a type equality into scope once (with a `Refl` pattern) and then being able to use that equality multiple times is both more convenient and more efficient than repeatedly `cast`ing.

**Edit**

chi points out that it is actually possible to do just one `cast` in this case:

```
checkEq a a' = (\eq -> eq a a') <$> cast ((==) @b)
checkEq a a' = uncurry ((==) @b) <$> cast (a, a')
```

In the general case, you can build a tuple of all the operations you need to cast, or all the values you need to cast. I guess this doesn't really leave me with a strong technical argument for either one over the other!

Comment: I 100% agree. There seems to be a way to use only a single `cast` but it's even more awkward: define `foo :: b -> b -> Maybe Bool` and then `case cast foo :: Maybe (a->b->Bool) of ...` which works because when `a~b` we have `(b->b->Bool)~(a->b->Bool)`. `eqT` is much simpler to use, and far more readable.

Comment: @chi Oh, nice! I'll include some commentary on that.